# Arc Hydro toolset to delineate surface drainage area

Tags: arc-hydro, arcgis-10.6

I need to determine the total amount of surface area that will drain to a given point in an urban environment. It seems that the Arc Hydro toolset can delineate the watershed that will drain to a given stream, but is there a tool that can be used to determine where precipitation runoff will go or the total surface area that will contribute runoff to a certain point?

To clarify, I don't need to calculate the amount of water that will drain to a point, just the surface area that will contribute to that amount.

Comment: Delineating a watershed for a point *is* determining "the surface area that will contribute to that amount." I have done this for urban watersheds before, and it's tricky because topography is not sufficient to delineate watershed boundaries accurately. Everything from which side of a building the downspouts are on, to underground tunnels/pipes/sewers can make an appreciable difference. I had to do quite a bit of field verification to get it right for some small watersheds in an urban area.

Comment: The specific contributing area is a raster that is output from any flow algorithm tool (e.g. D8, D-infinity). This land-surface parameter assigns the size of the upslope area to each grid cell, and visually examining these rasters will also help you to determine where the flow leaving a grid cell flows downslope. It's hard to describe without actually looking at one of these images.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mebtioned yet, the short answer to your question is that there is a button. Look for Point delineation in the Archydro toolbar. You need to have a flow direction grid and a few more things from the regular process, though, but you'll see when you click the button